# How can I check whether the Sim Card is available in an android device?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I need help checking whether a device has a sim card programatically. Please provide sample code.

Comment: What about CDMA phones that don't have sim cards?

Comment: @Senthil Mg Hey can you tell me how to get know if sim card is available in phone or not? I mean I tried with Telephony Manager but I can't get proper answer. Can you give me any simple example so that I can more understand.

Comment: @Mansi Vora,specify the problem you facing clearly,have you checked the below answer for this.

Comment: @Senthil Mg Yes I checked with below code and I have done my requirement. Thanks.. But now I want to know one more thing that when we dial a call from mobile at that time I want to check one condition so for that what should I do? At the time of Incoming call we used BroadcastReceiver at the same way how can we trace outgoing call.. Can you give me any idea.. I am confuse in this point. Thanks

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Use TelephonyManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

As Falmarri notes, you *will* want to use *getPhoneType* FIRST of all, to see if you are even dealing with a GSM phone. If you are, then you can also get the SIM state.

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
            switch (simState) {
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
                    // do something
                    break;
            }
```

---

**EDIT:**

Starting at API 26 (*Android O Preview*) you can query the SimState for individual sim slots by using `getSimState(int slotIndex)` ie:

```
int simStateMain = telMgr.getSimState(0);
int simStateSecond = telMgr.getSimState(1);
```

[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState(int))

If you're developing with and older api, you can use `TelephonyManager's`

```
String getDeviceId (int slotIndex)
//returns null if device ID is not available. ie. query slotIndex 1 in a single sim device

int devIdSecond = telMgr.getDeviceId(1);

//if(devIdSecond == null)
// no second sim slot available
```

which was added in API 23 - docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId(int))

Comment: thanks for your answer,let me know how to check whether the phone number entered is valid from phone directory

Comment: int simStateSecond = telMgr.getSimState(1);
it is giving error   method getSimState in class TelephonyManager cannot be applied to given types;
        int simState = telMgr.getSimState(0);

Answer (score 17):

You can check with the below code :

```
public static boolean isSimSupport(Context context)
    {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  //gets the current TelephonyManager
        return !(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT);

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found another way to do this.

```
public static boolean isSimStateReadyorNotReady() {
        int simSlotCount = sSlotCount;
        String simStates = SystemProperties.get("gsm.sim.state", "");
        if (simStates != null) {
            String[] slotState = simStates.split(",");
            int simSlot = 0;
            while (simSlot < simSlotCount && slotState.length > simSlot) {
                String simSlotState = slotState[simSlot];
                Log.d("MultiSimUtils", "isSimStateReadyorNotReady() : simSlot = " + simSlot + ", simState = " + simSlotState);
                if (simSlotState.equalsIgnoreCase("READY") || simSlotState.equalsIgnoreCase("NOT_READY")) {
                    return true;
                }
                simSlot++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It worked when using reflex this class android.os.SystemProperties

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Arun kumar answer, kotlin version as below

```
fun isSIMInserted(context: Context): Boolean {
    return TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT != (context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager).simState
}
```