# How to capture event of removal of SIM card in android?

Tags: android, sim-card

In android, how do I capture the event of SIM card removal? Usually on phones like htc 1x, we can remove the SIM card without removing the battery and there is no notification as such of power off or restart of the phone. I want to capture the event of SIM card removal, so that I can pop-up some messages.

Answer (score 2):

Check answer number one, You can check whether the sim card is available or not in device by using `TelephonyManager` class.

[How can I check whether the Sim Card is available in an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/to-check-sim-card-is-available-in-android-device)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553473), the system sends out an `android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED` intent when the SIM card when the SIM card changes, for example when entering or leaving airplane mode, and presumably also when removing or inserting a SIM card.
*It should be noted that as this is an undocumented API that may change  without notice, and it may also not be available on some devices.*

As for shutting down or restarting, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2190184), the system sends out an [`android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN) intent (on Android 1.6 or later).