# How to check phone in service State

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which i m checking service state of the phone but when phone is in flight mode its not responding, or phone dont have sim then also its not working.  plz help me  code is below

```
TelephonyManager telMng=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telMng.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){

                     @Override
                public void onServiceStateChanged (ServiceState serviceState){
                  super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
                  String phonestate;
                 switch(serviceState.getState())
                  {
                 case ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE:

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "phone is in service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     break;
                 case ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is not in Service state", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     break;
                     default:phonestate="Unknown";
                  }
                 /*

                  switch(serviceState.getState()){
                  case ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY: phonestate ="STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY"; ;break;
                  case ServiceState.STATE_IN_SERVICE: phonestate ="STATE_IN_SERVICE"; ;break;
                  case ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE: phonestate ="STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE"; ;break;
                  case ServiceState.STATE_POWER_OFF: phonestate ="STATE_POWER_OFF"; ;break;
                  default:phonestate = "Unknown";
                  } 
                  */  
            } 
        },  
        PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);

    }  
                                                                                                                                              i tried above code but its not working when phone is in flight mode or have not sim insert inside the phone what should i do plz help
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check whether the phone is on Airplane mode and if the sim card is present see this link

Airplane mode link:
[How can one detect airplane mode on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319212/how-can-one-detect-airplane-mode-on-android)

SIM card link:
[How can I check whether the Sim Card is available in an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device)

Comment: Thanks @DevfaR  its working now. again thanks from bottom of my heart

Comment: Down vote. This is not the correct answer. This will only tell if you if the sim is inserted not if it is in service

Answer (score 0):

The above isn't the correct answer since it only tells you if the sim card is in not if it is in service.

TelephonyManager.listen(PhoneStateListener() { ... }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);

should emmit the service state instantly AND periodically. You'll get the wrong results if you mix sim state and service state -- you'll be out of service, but sim state will still be ready.