# How to find Sim-card Network available or not?

Tags: android

How to find Sim Network available or not?

I don't want to check internet connection..but I want to check simcard is availble but simcard network is available or not

It is possible to find sim available(Sim State) in simslot . And also mobile internet available or not . But please give me suggestion of how to find network of sim-card is available or not in android programmatically .

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474089/how-to-check-currently-internet-connection-is-available-or-not-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check currently internet connection is available or not in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474089/how-to-check-currently-internet-connection-is-available-or-not-in-android)

Comment: possibe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device

Comment: i have tried below link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694440/check-if-a-sim-card-network-service-is-available-or-not . But it gives only sim state but not sim network availability.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device. this link also give sim state means sim available or not.But not give sim network availability

Comment: Use NetworkInfo it describes the status of a network interface of a given type (currently either Mobile or Wi-Fi).
 - see this : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing#java

Comment: @PriyaLalani means you want signal strength of simcard or mobile network right?

Comment: yes i want to find signal strength availability

Answer (score 2):

Check out below code it will provide you signal strength of mobile network:

Define Variables:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
MyPhoneStateListener mPhoneStatelistener;   
int mSignalStrength = 0;
```

Then add this class to your code:

```
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

     @Override
     public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
         super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
         mSignalStrength = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
         mSignalStrength = (2 * mSignalStrength) - 113; // -> dBm           
     }
 }
```

and in your onCreate method use:

```
mPhoneStatelistener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneStatelistener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

Comment: How to get signal strength of two different sim slot

Comment: @AMD:
refer this solution may it will help you to find out your solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767127/android-dual-sim-signal-strength