# How can I check whether Sim Cards are installed in both sim slots in an android device?

Tags: android, dual-sim

Guys I want to know if there are both the sims available and active in android dual sim phones irrespective of the device OS. I have already checked for few links that gives the result if the device is dual sim or not. But what I want to know is if there are two sim's installed in an android device. Please help me with a code snipnnet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device

Comment: Above link will check for primary sim state only

Answer (score 0):

Before API 22 you cannot detect if both the sims are present or not, though you can only check for single sim presence with `TelephonyManager` class in Android check more on [DOCS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and here is code snippet as well from  similar answered [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3982768/3521116)

From Android API 22

`getActiveSubscriptionInfoList` will get the `SubscriptionInfo(s)` of the currently inserted SIM(s). The records will be sorted by getSimSlotIndex() then by getSubscriptionId(). as mentioned on [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)

Comment: Yes.But I want to check for below API 22 devices too

Comment: I am afraid that you can't unless device manufacturer gives to access to their SDK, see similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: yo got the status for dual sim on phone on devices with api level below 22 care to share how ?

Comment: I tried this :  ` boolean isDualSimInstalled = false;
        TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(cordova.getActivity());
        if (telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready() && telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready()) {
            isDualSimInstalled = true;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Since api 22 there is [getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()) method you can call.

Comment: Yes.But I want to check for below API 22 devices too

Comment: @GautamiBhandary Check answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim