# How to check if SIM is active?

Tags: android

I have a use case where I need to check whether a SIM is active in the device. In older devices, I can use TelephonyManager to get the SIM state and check whether it is SIM_STATE_READY. The issue is with API 22 and above.

Using SubscriptionManager, when I call getActiveSubscriptionInfoList, it sends me details about the SIMs present, even if I have turned them off. I went through the documentation of SubscriptionManager but couldn't find a similar method to check SIM's state. Using TelephonyManager in API above 22 gives information only about the default SIM, I would like to know this about both slots in dual SIM phones. Also, I found an overloaded variant of getSimState in TelephonyManager which does accept the slot as a parameter, but that got introduced in API 26. I would like a solution that will work in APIs 22-25 as well.

Is there a way I could identify that even though the SIM is present in the device, it isn't active?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device
Did you check this link

Comment: Did you check the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSimState(int))

Comment: @RahulArora That link mentions getting deviceId for different slots which will just confirm the presence of a slot, it doesn't tell me if the SIM is active.

Comment: @TanveerMunir I did mention that method in my question, the issue is that it was introduced in API 26. I need something similar which will work for APIs 22-25.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad I think you are asking about that `getActiveSubscriptionInfoList` which is available in API 22 please have to look at this [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)

Comment: @TanveerMunir As mentioned in my question, that method returns the SIM details even if I turn off the SIM from phone settings.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad I post my answer hope that's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by like this if Device is dual sim

```
    SubscriptionManager sManager = (SubscriptionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);
        SubscriptionInfo infoSim1 = sManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(0);
        SubscriptionInfo infoSim2 = sManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(1);
        int count = 0;
        if (infoSim1 != null ) {
            count++;
        }
        if (infoSim2 != null){
            count++;
        }
```

count decides that how many sims are active.

**OR**

You can get the count then check one by one

```
sManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoCount()
```

Hope it's work.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already tried this. The returned object isn't null even if you turn off the SIM from the phone settings.

Comment: You mentioned that you are using `getActiveSubscriptionInfoList` this method not this `getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(0)` according doc it's return null if sim is not in an active state.

Comment: getActiveSubscriptionInfoList returns an array and getActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex returns individually according to the slot. Both of them return the info of the SIM which is present but turned off.

Comment: @HimanshuPrasad yes I know that but according to document its returns null if the sim is not active.

Comment: @TanveerMunir then share the doc link if possible

Comment: after disable the sim getting __SubscriptionInfo __ object not __null__ value

Answer (score 0):

```
 TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (manager.getPhoneCount() == 2) {
  // Dual sim
}
```

[Examples here](https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.telephony.TelephonyManager/getPhoneCount)