# How to check if the Android Tablet has simcard feature programatically?

Tags: android, android-networking, ringtonemanager

How can i check Android tablet using Android app ,if it has sim card (4g) feature or not. since i have created an App that has to perform different Task depending on  if it has simcard (4g) phone feature or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to play around with TelephoneyManager to test if it has simcard slot or not .
to be exect try below code.  more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981007/how-can-i-check-whether-the-sim-card-is-available-in-an-android-device/3982768#3982768)

```
public static boolean isSimSupport(Context context)
    {
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);  //gets the current TelephonyManager
        return !(tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT);

    }
```